# Why is this Typescript interface causing a null exception in runtime bundling?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, typescript, bundling-and-minification

I started a new MVC Razor test web project in VS 2013. I updated all NuGet packages to the latest versions as at today and started including my TypeScript plugins from another project to test. One of the plugins caused this run-time error:

### Error with Stack-trace:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
Line 39:     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
Line 40:     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
Line 41:     @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ListView")
Line 42:     @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
Line 43: </body> 
Stack Trace: 

[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseUnaryExpression(Boolean& isLeftHandSideExpr, Boolean isMinus) +298
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement) +125
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment) +1552
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock() +164
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment) +498
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseLabeledStatement(Lookup lookup, Boolean fSourceElement) +543
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseExpressionStatement(Boolean fSourceElement) +226
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment) +1552
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock() +164
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment) +498
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseBlock() +164
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatement(Boolean fSourceElement, Boolean skipImportantComment) +498
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.ParseStatements(Block block) +159
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.InternalParse() +1011
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext) +123
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.JSParser.Parse(DocumentContext sourceContext, CodeSettings settings) +54
   Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities.Minifier.MinifyJavaScript(String source, CodeSettings codeSettings) +987
   System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify.Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response) +310
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.ApplyTransforms(BundleContext context, String bundleContent, IEnumerable`1 bundleFiles) +263
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GenerateBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +355
   System.Web.Optimization.Bundle.GetBundleResponse(BundleContext context) +104
   System.Web.Optimization.BundleResolver.GetBundleContents(String virtualPath) +254
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.DeterminePathsToRender(IEnumerable`1 assets) +252
   System.Web.Optimization.AssetManager.RenderExplicit(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +75
   System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.RenderFormat(String tagFormat, String[] paths) +292
   System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render(String[] paths) +51
   ASP._Page_views_shared__LayoutHome_cshtml.Execute() in e:\HiTechMagic\iCollectIt\iCollectIt.CloudServices\iCollectit.Collector.WebApplication\Views\Shared\_LayoutHome.cshtml:41
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +120
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +335
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +53
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +178
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +347
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9688704
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I removed all code, and files, until I narrowed it down to an example that fails with just this:

### BundleConfig.cs

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ListView").Include(
           "~/Scripts/Vero/reorder.ts"));
```

### reorder.ts

```
module Plugins
{
    export interface IReorderOptions
    {
        onChange: { (): void; };         // Function to call after update
    }
}
```

### Master page _LayoutHome.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    [SNIP]
<body>
    [SNIP]

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ListView")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

And my Home/Index references the master page with:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/views/shared/_layoutHome.cshtml";
}
```

Basically it looks like the code that builds the JS output/bundle is breaking on the declaration of my interface with a function, but I cannot find a pattern to it.

The full plugin worked fine in previous web applications, so I suspect one of the NuGet/VS tools has changed. The `reorder.js` output file is obviously empty, so it looks like it may be the TypeScript parsing.

I hope the stack-trace (above) and log (below) give a clue. I hope it is actually something obvious I am missing or have done wrong with the declaration.

### The output log (last part due to SO size limits):

```
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8d1fcf70\6d8beac0\App_Web_2rxc12vp.dll'. 
    'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/44/ROOT-1-130403001817617541): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
    A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/44/ROOT-1-130403001817617541): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8d1fcf70\6d8beac0\App_Web_fivluysz.dll'. 
    A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebGrease.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebGrease.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll
    'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet Explorer)'. 
    The program '[6296] iexplore.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The program '[11616] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### A: Make sure you always reference the .js file (not .ts)!

Hopefully this question and answer may be useful to someone else *that makes the same stupid mistake I did* and gets the same unhelpful error message!

I accidentally referenced the `.ts` file instead of the `.js` file one in the bundle... just on one plugin (the one that broke). All my changes did nothing to fix the *now glaringly obvious* problem.

## D'oh! :)